Influence of electron's kinetic energy disspation during photoelectric effect
What are the properties of a metal that determine its work function?
What has a greater influence on its value: the electromagnetic energy of
an electron (which is going to leave metal's volume because of photoelectric emission) and the atoms of
the metal or the dissipation of electron's kinetic energy in the process of
THIS electron leaving the volume of the metal?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It sounds like you are saying there is an energy difference between an electron bound to the metal and a free electron. And you are also saying there is an energy lost when an atom escapes from the metal, perhaps because it bumps into atoms along the way. Is this right?

Yes, all of this is true
